# Scale bug with hover a div

Tags: html, css, hover

Im new with HTML & CSS and this is my first question. I tried to make a box who scales from `1.0` to `0.8` when you hover it with your mouse.

It works fine when you're with the mouse in the middle (`0.0` between `0.8`) on the box.

But when you are between `0.8` and `1.0` area it goes crazy everytime I move my mouse.

I would like that the box scales to `0.8` when you hover the whole `1.0` area at any time. It should be scale back to `1.0` when I leave the fixed `1.0` area. Not any other area. I cant help myself.

**Test it or see it:** https://jsfiddle.net/cyLxLbya/

**YouTube Video:** https://youtu.be/4MT4hrK7DVE 
(left is between 0-0.8, right goes crazy between 0.8-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your scroll event triggering and blurring while the element scales. You're detecting a :hover but when the element gets small enough it loses it's :hover state and tries to scale up again. And back again (as it goes into :hover again).

One of the ways to fix this would be to detect the hover on a parent element (that doesn't scale). For example: https://jsfiddle.net/cyLxLbya/1/

```
.box{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 83px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    transition: all 200ms ease;
    transition-duration: 0.2s; 
}

.hover:hover .box{
    transform: scale(0.8);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 24px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

It's also advisable to move the transition to the box itself (not the hover state of the box).

Comment: As for the HTML this isn't a really neat solution. If it's just for effect you're probably better off using a :after or :before to create the effect.

Comment: That is the "solution" Thank you it worked! I didnt even know you can do this in CSS.